# Passing a member-access function in the constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, delegates, member

Let's say I have a helper class like

```
public class Selection<T, W> : ISelection<T,W> where W : ICollection<T>
{
    public Selection(Func<W> selectableItemsProvider)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As C# does not support delegating interface implementation, I thought I'd save myself a bit of boilerplate and just extend the `Selection` class...

```
public class MyFoo : Selection<Blah, List<Blah>>
{
    private List<Blah> _blahs = new List<Blah>();


    public MyFoo() : base(() => _blahs)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Except I cannot do that, can I, because

> Cannot access non-static property '_blahs' in static context

even though **I** already know the provider won't be invoked until after object construction.

Is there a way around this or am I stuck with adding boilerplate code?

Comment: Add protected empty constructor then allow to just assign `selectableItemsProvider` directly (make it protected member for example)?

Comment: You mean the provider won't be invoked in the `Selection` constructor?

Comment: @Sweeper exactly.

Comment: I'd do as @Evk suggested: `protected Func<W> SelectableItemsProvider { get; }`, `protected Selection() { }`, `public MyFoo() { SelectableItemsProvider = () => _blahs; }`

Comment: @Evk but then I can no longer require that a provider is set after object instantiation.

Comment: Is that helper class ever used directly or you always going to inherit from it?

Comment: @Evk For the use case I'm introducing it now for, I should be fine with inheriting from it, I cannot make guarantees to future uses.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to first introduce base abstract class. This class will hold all the logic:

```
public abstract class SelectionBase<T, W> where W : ICollection<T>
{
    protected SelectionBase() {

    }

    protected abstract Func<W> GetSelectableItemsProvider();
}
```

Then change your current `Selection` to inherit from it and accept selector in constructor, that's the whole implementation:

```
public sealed class Selection<T, W> : SelectionBase<T, W> where W: ICollection<T> {
    private readonly Func<W> _selectableItemsProvider;

    public Selection(Func<W> selectableItemsProvider) {
        _selectableItemsProvider = selectableItemsProvider;
    }

    protected override Func<W> GetSelectableItemsProvider() {
        return _selectableItemsProvider;
    }
}
```

Now if you want to extend selection in a way mentioned in your question:

```
public class SpecificSelection : SelectionBase<string, List<string>> {
    private List<string> _blah;

    public SpecificSelection() {

    }

    protected override Func<List<string>> GetSelectableItemsProvider() {
        return () => _blah;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One somewhat roundabout way to do this is to pass a lambda that returns the same list every time to the base class constructor. Then call that lambda to  initialise `blahs`:

```
public class Selection<T, W>: ISelection<T, W> where W : ICollection<T> {

    // assuming you have a property like this that is initialised by the constructor...
    protected Func<W> SelectableItemsProvider { get; }
    public Selection(Func<W> selectableItemsProvider)
    {
        SelectableItemsProvider = selectableItemsProvider;
    }
}

public class MyFoo : Selection<Blah, List<Blah>>
{
    private List<Blah> _blahs;


    public MyFoo() : base(new List<Blah>().CaptureInFunc())
    {
        _blahs = SelectableItemsProvider();
    }
}
```

`CaptureInFunc` is an extension method declared like this:

```
public static Func<T> CaptureInFunc<T>(this T t) => () => t;
```

This gives us a lambda that returns `t` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to members of 'this' in the call to a base constructor because 'this' does not exist yet.

I suggest composition instead of inheritance. The class may still implement the same interface as the helper and then delegate all calls to the real implementation.

```cs
public class MyFoo : ISelection<Blah, List<Blah>>
{
    private List<Blah> _blahs;
    
    private ISelection<Blah, List<Blah>> _implementation;

    public MyFoo()
    {
        _blahs = new List<Blah>();
        _implementation = new Selection<Blah, List<Blah>>(() => _blahs);
    }
    
    public void DoSomethingWithSelection()
    {
        _implementation.DoSomethingWithSelection();
    }
}
```